# Нужно ли ограничивать доступ к Action?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net

При разработке веб приложения обнаружил что доступ к Action который осуществляется при подгрузке данных с помощью js в самом приложении, можно получить и вне приложения
`domain.name/Home/Action`.
Не знаю стоит ли ограничить доступ к этому "api" для пользователей, чтобы сервер не нагружался. Дайте совет, как правильнее. Спасибо.

Comment: `domain.name/Home/Action` возвращает ответ в виде json

Comment: Простой вопрос, на который вы сами должны ответить - "Вы хотите давать эти данные сторонним людям?" Если да - оставляйте, если нет - ограничивайте. Если это ваша внутренняя информация, то странно, что вы делаете API доступ для нее тогда...

Comment: если javascript, который вы запускаете на клиенте в браузере, делает какие то вызовы на ваш бекенд, то юзер точно также может такие вызовы делать самостоятельно, без джаваскриптов. Ограниение доступа к API означает, что юзер не может вызвать этот API, и вы также с браузера юзера его не можете вызвать.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы пытаетесь ограничить доступ к api, который вы используете для динамической загрузки контента, вместе с js, для того чтобы некий "Иван" в своем приложении не делал к вашему приложению 100500+ запросов в секунду, то ограничивать его не стоит, так как он даже без api может, как в гайдах про парсинг, полностью скачать вашу страницу, что уже является большей нагрузкой чем  через api. А вообще, насколько я понял, чтобы ограничить доступ к подобным запросам от пользователя, надо отказаться от js на стороне клиента, и делать загрузку данных вместе с обновлением страницы, как при post запросе. Правильно ли я сделал выводы? Поправьте если не прав.

Comment: неправильно ты сделал вывод.

Comment: @Grundy можете пожалуйста указать на мои ошибки.

Comment: Ограничение != производительность. Вот у вас наверно дома есть WiFi, который имеет пароль, через него все ваши **беспроводные** устройства выходят в интернет. Почему у WiFi пароль? Наверно, вы не хотите, чтоб ваши соседи пользовались вашим интернетом, верно? Если бы вы хотели этого, то сеть была открыта, либо частично открыта (гостевая). Теперь другой вопрос - почему у вас дома WiFi? Наверно у вас есть устройства, которые без провода подключаются в интернет... Ок, а если таких устройств нет? Нужен WiFi? Наверно нет, бессмысленно, проще и надежней проводом, внутри квартиры все подцепить.

Comment: Вот сайт, это все тоже самое, где у вас есть некий адрес, который дает некую информацию, без разницы какую и как, он просто дает ее. Вот вы хотите, чтоб другие люди имели к ней доступ? Если да - ограничивать ничего не надо. Нет - Ставьте авторизацию. Все, на этом как бы точка, какие-то там нагрузки и так далее, это ерунда. Почему? А потому, что без разницы какой запрос вам отправляют клиенты, это новое соединение, новая нагрузка. Открыл страницу - нагрузка, отправил вам PING запрос - нагрузка, API - нагрузка, соккет - нагрузка. Так что, с точки "оптимизации" смотреть не стоит.